# Collapsible data row with dynamic values

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, knockout.js

Context: There are a set of months in a table (e.g. May, Jun, July) and under those months will be all of the readings for the given month.

The code:

```
<tbody data-bind="visible: !MeterReadingHistory_IsBusy(), foreach: HeaderLines()" style="display: none">
                        <tr data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".order1">
                            <td>
                                <!-- ko if: meterReadings.length > 0-->
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></span>
                                <span class="reading-history-data" data-bind="html: monthName"></span>
                                <!-- /ko -->
                                <!-- ko if: meterReadings.length == 0-->
                                <span class="reading-history-data" data-bind="html: monthName"></span>
                                <!-- /ko -->
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <span class="reading-history-data" data-bind="html: latestReadingDate"></span>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <span class="reading-history-data" data-bind="html: latestReadingType"></span>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <span class="reading-history-data" data-bind="html: latestReadingElectric"></span>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <span class="reading-history-data" data-bind="html: latestReadingGas"></span>
                            </td>
                        </tr>


                        <!-- ko if: meterReadings.length > 0 -->
                        <tr class="collapse order1" >
                            <td colspan="5">

                                <table class="table mb-none desktop-only">
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th>Day</th>
                                            <th>Reading Source</th>
                                            <th>Electricity</th>
                                            <th>Gas</th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>
                                        <!-- ko foreach: meterReadings -->
                                        <tr>
                                            <td data-bind="text: readingDateParsed"></td>
                                            <td data-bind="html: readingType"></td>
                                            <!-- ko foreach: readings -->
                                            <td data-bind="html: reading"></td>
                                            <!-- /ko -->
                                            <!-- ko if: readings.length == 0 -->
                                            <td></td>
                                            <td></td>
                                            <!-- /ko -->
                                            <!-- ko if: readings.length == 1 -->
                                            <td></td>
                                            <!-- /ko -->
                                        </tr>
                                        <!-- /ko -->
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <!-- /ko -->
                    </tbody>
```

The problem: When i click on any of the rows, it expands every month row exposing all of the data when in fact i only want to display the sub-rows for the actual month that has been clicked.

The main problem is that this table is dynamic, and we wont know how many header rows will be produced, therefore it will be difficult to assign each row to a specific data source via the data-bind attribute.

So......how can I get this code to display only the row of data that I have clicked on, e.g. May, and display all the readings for this given month while all of the other header rows remain closed?

Thanks!

Comment: You can use `$index()` to create "unique" targets in your loop. (Every element rendered by the `foreach` has its own index.) However: knockout doesn't really like other code (such as your bootstrap framework) modifying the DOM. Try to google for "custom bootstrap bindings" to make sure stuff keeps working.

Answer (score 0):

```
$([data-toggle="collapse"]).on('click',function(){
    var thisCollapse = $(this).attr('data-target');
    $(thisCollapse).slideToggle('slow');
})
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to do anything :(

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.